# concat_ws retruns blank values when all value are null , i need NULL when all value are null

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark

I am writing a script in pyspark where we are doing transformation of data.
I am using `contact_ws` function to contact value while doing `group by`.The problem I am facing here is if all value in `concat_ws` are `null` than it will retrung blank value. so whem i am trying to insert new transformed data in mysql table  it will give me error like ''

> can not be inserted in database.

to fix this problem we need to have `null` value when all value in `concat_ws` function are `null`.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the following dataframe

```
df.show()

+----+----+----+
|val1|val2|val3|
+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
|   d|   e|null|
|   g|null|null|
|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+
```

and you want to concatenate `val1`, `val2` and `val3` in a new column `concat`.

As you said, the default behavior of `concat_ws` is to return an empty string if all the inputs are `null`:

```scala
df.withColumn("concat", concat_ws("_", 'val1, 'val2, 'val3)).show()
```

```
+----+----+----+------+
|val1|val2|val3|concat|
+----+----+----+------+
|   a|   b|   c| a_b_c|
|   d|   e|null|   d_e|
|   g|null|null|     g|
|null|null|null|      |
+----+----+----+------+
```

You have many options to obtain a `null` value instead of an empty string:

#### Option 1: call `concat_ws` and then replace all empty values with null

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
var withConcat = df.withColumn("concat", concat_ws("_", 'val1, 'val2, 'val3)).show()
withConcat.withColumn("concat", when('concat.equalTo(""), lit(null).cast(StringType)).otherwise('concat)).show()
```

```
+----+----+----+------+
|val1|val2|val3|concat|
+----+----+----+------+
|   a|   b|   c| a_b_c|
|   d|   e|null|   d_e|
|   g|null|null|     g|
|null|null|null|  null|
+----+----+----+------+
```

#### Option 2: don't call `concat_ws` if all the values are `null`

```scala
df.withColumn("concat", when(coalesce('val1, 'val2, 'val3).isNull, lit(null).cast(StringType)).otherwise(concat_ws("_", 'val1, 'val2, 'val3))).show()
```

```
+----+----+----+------+
|val1|val2|val3|concat|
+----+----+----+------+
|   a|   b|   c| a_b_c|
|   d|   e|null|   d_e|
|   g|null|null|     g|
|null|null|null|  null|
+----+----+----+------+
```

> Note: the code is in scala but it can be easily adapted to pyspark